# SearchView show not well

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I use the ToolsBar that make the Actionbar, and add a SearchView in menu. But
not show well, the “Search” Text multi-line. 
If theres a way move the Search when i press the search close button.

[image: picture]

Comment: Where is [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) ?

Comment: do you want to implement a searchview on the actionbar?

Comment: Yes.I has been implemented a searchview on the actionbar by android.support.v7.widget.SearchView ,But not well, the "Search" Text muti-line. [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FX1z1.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself,  custom SearchView use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="@dimen/default_elevation">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_title"
            android:name="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tools_bar_title_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_search_root"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_search_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_search_actionbar_white_bg"
                android:hint="Enter Keywords"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_search_action"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_search_clean"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_white_close"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```